# start output from first match

Tags: bash, grep

i have a command that prints out some statistical information that looks like this:

```
Detailed Hardware Status Dump:

...

Summary:

Memory info: OK
HDD info:  OK
...
```

I'd like to `./dump_hw_status | grep 'Summary:'` so that grep start to output everything from the first line matching 'Summary:'

is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
./dump_hw_status | sed -n '/^Summary:/,$p'
```

This will print everything from the line starting with "Summary:" to the end of the file.